# Calculated column comparing two dates

Tags: date-time, calculated-column-formula

I can't seem to get my formula working.

All I need is to compare 2 date fields:

The out of the box `[Modified]` and a custom `[Published Date]`.

The published date is empty until filled by a workflow.

What I want is a calculated column called `Republish` which says `yes` if `[Modified]` is greater than `[Published date]`.

I'm struggling with the `ISBLANK` condition. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Go through this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with this formula.

```
=IF([Published Date]="";"";IF([Published Date]>Modified;"";"yes"))
```

Be aware that this formula is created in a German language SharePoint. I am not sure if English SharePoint uses semicolon (;) or comma (,) to seperate formulas. So if you get a formula error just replace the semicolons with commas.

Proof of concept:

[image]

**If this solution helps please mark as answer/vote!**

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Published date]), "", IF([Modified]>[Published date], "Yes",""))
```